# Angular dependency errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting serveral issues on npm install with the peer dependencies. It only works on my workstation and it occured after i add a simple mat-date-picker... Here is my package.json and i already tried every possible command sucha as npm install --save --force etc...

```
{
  "name": "ap-iproj-porto",
  "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Description for APIprojPorto",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "app:start": "./mvnw",
    "backend:build-cache": "./mvnw dependency:go-offline",
    "backend:debug": "./mvnw -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments=\"-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000\"",
    "backend:doc:test": "./mvnw -ntp javadoc:javadoc --batch-mode",
    "backend:info": "./mvnw -ntp enforcer:display-info --batch-mode",
    "backend:nohttp:test": "./mvnw -ntp checkstyle:check --batch-mode",
    "backend:start": "./mvnw -Dskip.installnodenpm -Dskip.npm",
    "backend:unit:test": "./mvnw -ntp -Dskip.installnodenpm -Dskip.npm verify --batch-mode -Dlogging.level.ROOT=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.zalando=OFF -Dlogging.level.tech.jhipster=OFF -Dlogging.level.com.cmporto.api=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.web=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=OFF",
    "build": "npm run webapp:prod --",
    "build-watch": "concurrently 'npm run webapp:build:dev -- --watch' npm:backend:start",
    "ci:backend:test": "npm run backend:info && npm run backend:doc:test && npm run backend:nohttp:test && npm run backend:unit:test -- -P$npm_package_config_default_environment",
    "ci:e2e:package": "npm run java:$npm_package_config_packaging:$npm_package_config_default_environment -- -Pe2e -Denforcer.skip=true",
    "ci:e2e:prepare": "npm run ci:e2e:prepare:docker",
    "ci:e2e:prepare:docker": "npm run docker:db:up && npm run docker:others:up && docker ps -a",
    "ci:e2e:run": "concurrently -k -s first \"npm run ci:e2e:server:start\" \"npm run e2e:headless\"",
    "preci:e2e:server:start": "npm run docker:db:await --if-present && npm run docker:others:await --if-present",
    "ci:e2e:server:start": "java -jar target/e2e.$npm_package_config_packaging --spring.profiles.active=e2e,$npm_package_config_default_environment -Dlogging.level.ROOT=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.zalando=OFF -Dlogging.level.tech.jhipster=OFF -Dlogging.level.com.cmporto.api=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.web=OFF -Dlogging.level.org.springframework.security=OFF --logging.level.org.springframework.web=ERROR",
    "ci:e2e:teardown": "npm run ci:e2e:teardown:docker",
    "ci:e2e:teardown:docker": "npm run docker:db:down --if-present && npm run docker:others:down && docker ps -a",
    "ci:frontend:build": "npm run webapp:build:$npm_package_config_default_environment",
    "ci:frontend:test": "npm run ci:frontend:build && npm test",
    "ci:server:await": "echo \"Waiting for server at port $npm_package_config_backend_port to start\" && wait-on -t 180000 http-get://localhost:$npm_package_config_backend_port/management/health && echo \"Server at port $npm_package_config_backend_port started\"",
    "clean-coverage": "rimraf .nyc_output coverage",
    "clean-www": "rimraf target/classes/static/app/{src,target/}",
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/classes/static/",
    "cypress": "cypress open --e2e",
    "docker:app:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/app.yml up -d",
    "docker:db:down": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/postgresql.yml down -v",
    "docker:db:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/postgresql.yml up -d",
    "docker:elasticsearch:down": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml down -v",
    "docker:elasticsearch:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/elasticsearch.yml up -d",
    "docker:jhipster-registry:await": "echo \"Waiting for jhipster-registry to start\" && wait-on -t 180000 http-get://localhost:8761/management/health && echo \"jhipster-registry started\"",
    "docker:jhipster-registry:down": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/jhipster-registry.yml down -v",
    "docker:jhipster-registry:up": "docker-compose -f src/main/docker/jhipster-registry.yml up -d",
    "docker:others:await": "echo \"Waiting for Elasticsearch to start\" && wait-on -t 180000 \"http-get://localhost:9200/_cluster/health?wait_for_status=green&timeout=60s\" && echo \"Elasticsearch started\" && npm run docker:jhipster-registry:await",
    "docker:others:down": "npm run docker:elasticsearch:down && npm run docker:jhipster-registry:down",
    "predocker:others:up": "",
    "docker:others:up": "npm run docker:elasticsearch:up && npm run docker:jhipster-registry:up",
    "e2e": "npm run e2e:cypress:headed --",
    "e2e:cypress": "cypress run --e2e --browser chrome --record ${CYPRESS_ENABLE_RECORD:-false}",
    "pree2e:cypress:coverage": "npm run clean coverage && npm run ci:server:await",
    "e2e:cypress:coverage": "npm run e2e:cypress:headed",
    "poste2e:cypress:coverage": "nyc report",
    "e2e:cypress:headed": "npm run e2e:cypress -- --headed",
    "e2e:dev": "concurrently -k -s first \"./mvnw\" \"npm run e2e\"",
    "e2e:devserver": "concurrently -k -s first \"npm run backend:start\" \"npm start\" \"wait-on -t 180000 http-get://localhost:9000 && npm run e2e:headless -- -c baseUrl=http://localhost:9000\"",
    "pree2e:headless": "npm run ci:server:await",
    "e2e:headless": "npm run e2e:cypress --",
    "java:docker": "./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests -Pprod jib:dockerBuild",
    "java:docker:arm64": "npm run java:docker -- -Djib-maven-plugin.architecture=arm64",
    "java:docker:dev": "npm run java:docker -- -Pdev,webapp",
    "java:docker:prod": "npm run java:docker -- -Pprod",
    "java:jar": "./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests --batch-mode",
    "java:jar:dev": "npm run java:jar -- -Pdev,webapp",
    "java:jar:prod": "npm run java:jar -- -Pprod",
    "java:war": "./mvnw -ntp verify -DskipTests --batch-mode -Pwar",
    "java:war:dev": "npm run java:war -- -Pdev,webapp",
    "java:war:prod": "npm run java:war -- -Pprod",
    "jest": "jest --coverage --logHeapUsage --maxWorkers=2 --config jest.conf.js",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.ts",
    "lint:fix": "npm run lint -- --fix",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "prettier:check": "prettier --check \"{,src/**/,webpack/,.blueprint/**/}*.{md,json,yml,html,cjs,mjs,js,ts,tsx,css,scss,java}\"",
    "prettier:format": "prettier --write \"{,src/**/,webpack/,.blueprint/**/}*.{md,json,yml,html,cjs,mjs,js,ts,tsx,css,scss,java}\"",
    "serve": "npm run start --",
    "start": "ng serve --hmr",
    "start-tls": "npm run webapp:dev-ssl",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "ng test --coverage --log-heap-usage -w=2",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
    "watch": "concurrently npm:start npm:backend:start",
    "webapp:build": "npm run clean-www && npm run webapp:build:dev",
    "webapp:build:dev": "ng build --configuration development",
    "webapp:build:prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "webapp:dev": "ng serve",
    "webapp:dev-ssl": "ng serve --ssl",
    "webapp:dev-verbose": "ng serve --verbose",
    "prewebapp:instrumenter": "npm run clean-www && npm run clean-coverage",
    "webapp:instrumenter": "ng build --configuration instrumenter",
    "webapp:prod": "npm run clean-www && npm run webapp:build:prod",
    "webapp:test": "npm run test --"
  },
  "config": {
    "backend_port": "8080",
    "default_environment": "prod",
    "packaging": "jar"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "14.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.11.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.2.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "7.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "2.11.6",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.0",
    "angular-material-clock-time-picker": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "5.2.0",
    "bootswatch": "5.2.0",
    "dayjs": "1.11.5",
    "leaflet": "^1.9.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mat-timepicker": "^5.1.8",
    "material": "^0.5.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "14.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "10.0.1",
    "papaparse": "^5.3.2",
    "requests": "^0.3.0",
    "rxjs": "7.5.6",
    "tslib": "2.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.11.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "14.0.1",
    "@angular-builders/jest": "14.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "14.2.1",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "14.0.3",
    "@angular/cli": "14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "14.2.0",
    "@angular/service-worker": "14.2.0",
    "@cypress/code-coverage": "3.10.0",
    "@types/jest": "28.1.8",
    "@types/node": "16.11.56",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.3.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.36.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.36.1",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.5",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "6.1.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.27.11",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "concurrently": "7.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "11.0.0",
    "cypress": "10.7.0",
    "eslint": "8.23.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.12.1",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "folder-hash": "4.0.2",
    "generator-jhipster": "7.9.3",
    "husky": "7.0.4",
    "jest": "28.1.3",
    "jest-date-mock": "1.0.8",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "28.1.3",
    "jest-junit": "14.0.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "12.2.2",
    "jest-sonar": "0.2.12",
    "lint-staged": "13.0.3",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1",
    "nyc": "15.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-java": "1.6.2",
    "prettier-plugin-packagejson": "2.2.18",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "swagger-ui-dist": "4.14.0",
    "ts-jest": "28.0.8",
    "typescript": "4.8.2",
    "wait-on": "6.0.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.6.1",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.15.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.17.0"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "overrides": {
    "webpack": "5.74.0"
  }
}
```

-I tried to remove node_modules and type npm install
-I tried run npm install --save --force on the other pcs and did not work
-I tried npm cache clean --force

my: npm list
[npm command list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od7eK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because you have incompatible dependencies.

In your `package.json` you have `@angular/material` in version `7.0.0` defined, but this version is only compatible with Angular 7.
Then there is `@angular/animations` in version `15.1.1`, but this version needs Angular in version 15. Also `mat-timepicker` requires `@angular/material` in version 14.

Try installing the correct versions of `@angular/animations` and `@angular/material`.

```
npm i @angular/animations@14 @angular/material@14
```

You may need to run npm install with the `--force` flag.

The following changes to the `package.json` should resolve all peer dependency warnings and errors (*only changed lines are included*). The main problem currently are the peer dependencies of `mat-timepicker`. These are very strict, [see the the source code](https://github.com/IliaIdakiev/angular-material-timepicker/blob/master/projects/mat-timepicker/package.json#L4) of the `mat-timepicker`. There is also [an open issue](https://github.com/IliaIdakiev/angular-material-timepicker/issues/88) which addresses this problem.

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^14.1.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "14.1.3",
  "@angular/common": "^14.1.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^14.1.0",
  "@angular/core": "^14.1.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^14.1.0",
  "@angular/localize": "^14.1.0",
  "@angular/material": "14.1.3",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.1.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.1.0",
  "@angular/router": "^14.1.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.1.0",
  "@angular/service-worker": "^14.1.0"
}
```

After applying these changes to the `package.json` run `npm update`.

There maybe some adjustments needed for the new version of `@angular/material` to work correctly. Version 7 was released in 2018. With seven major versions released, you can expect some breaking changes.

[This blog post has also some information](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) about peer dependencies and why these problems occur.

Comment: Thank you for the help but gave me more issues :/npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/cdk@14.2.7, required by @angular/material@14.2.7
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@14.2.12, required by @angular/animations@14.2.12
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/material@14.1.3, required by mat-timepicker@5.1.8
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@5.2.11, required by @angular/http@5.2.11
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11, required by @angular/http@5.2.11
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^5.5.0, required by @angular/http@5.2.11

Comment: Installing `@angular/material@14` will install the newest version available, which seems to require `@angular/cdk@14.2.7`. I think if you prefix the version as recommended from Angular with a `^` in the `package.json` and run `npm update` it should resolve the problems. This will allow npm to install all new minor and patch versions of the packages. An alternative would be to install the exact version `@angular/material@14.2.3`. For `@angular/http` you could try to run `npm list @angular/http` to see which package requires the outdated package.

Comment: It is getting more errors :peer dep missing: @angular/core@14.2.0, required by @angular/common@14.2.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@14.2.0, required by @angular/forms@14.2.0
- There is no trick to solve this dependency problems?

Comment: @RafaelOliveira I've updated my answer, which now includes the required changes to the `package.json` and also linked to an open issue of the `mat-timepicker` library which is likely the main problem of your peer dependency problems.

Comment: That solved a lot of them but a new one appeared:peer dep missing: @angular/cdk@14.1.3, required by @angular/material@14.1.3
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@5.2.11, required by @angular/http@5.2.11
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/platform-browser@5.2.11, required by @angular/http@5.2.11
npm ERR! peer dep missing: rxjs@^5.5.0, required by @angular/http@5.2.11
Do you know how to fix them?

Comment: Try to run `npm list @angular/http`, as written before, to see which package requires the outdated `@angular/http` package. This should help you identify the remaining package to update/remove. Since the `mat-timepicker` requires an exact Angular Material version and this requires the same CDK Version, so one option would be to set booth to `14.1.3` in `package.json`. The best thing would be if the developer of `mat-timepicker` would not set the peer dependency version exactly but allow all 14.x.x versions.

Comment: Now is asking me to donwgrade my core to 5.2.11??? I guess that im going to discard my mat-datepicker component... peer dep missing: @angular/core@5.2.11, required by @angular/http@5.2.11

Comment: Are you using the `angular-material-clock-time-picker` package? Seems this is the one which requires `@angular/http` and has the peer dependency of `@angular/core@5.2.11`. I would recommend uninstalling this. Then the last error should also be gone. The package was last updated 5 years ago.

Comment: Im trying that now, do you know any date picker package that is compatible with angular 14.2.0?

Comment: If you only want to select a date, then the [Datepicker from Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview). For a time picker I have no recommendation. I think I would go with the default HTML Time Input and just use the Material Design.

Comment: Now that i deleted the time picker the angular datepicker is displaying a weird calendar… with everything deformed

Comment: Time Picker and Date Picker are two completely different things. [Check the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview) to see if the Date Picker is what you want. It could be that the many different packages you are using influence each other's design. But that goes beyond the actual topic of this question and is best answered separately.

Comment: I found the problem... it was on @angular/material that i had with the version 14.2.0 and it only display correct with the 7.3.7 version. The problem is with the peer dependency, that needs a cdk with the same version but my whole project is with  the version 14.2.0.. any solution for that?

Comment: I oppened a recent question for the problem, check it please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75486658/angular-material-peer-dependency-problem-enters-in-cycle

Comment: You should make sure that your implementation of the Date Picker is up to date with the newly installed version, check the documentation. As written in my answer, breaking changes are to be expected when updating a package from version 7 to 14, that are seven major versions.